# Ionic : Execution failed for task ':processDebugResources'

Tags: android, ionic-framework

I am trying to run an android project done on ionic. When i build the project using `ionic build android`
The log shows

```
:processDebugResources/home/user/myProject/platforms/android/build/intermediates/manifests/full/debug/AndroidManifest.xml:24:23-37 : AAPT: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'icon' with value '@drawable/icon').
```

I have found the drawable folders for different screen sizes in `myProject->platforms->android->resource` folder and there is no image icon named icon.png inside any of those folders. So i pasted a png image named icon.png in all those folders  and started building the project again. But still i get the same error.how could i solve it?

Comment: Generate the icon path using this command:

ionic resources --icon

then build the application.

Comment: better you add android platform again and build

Comment: still doesn't work